# Override class in "porto" architecture

Tags: php, laravel, logic, overriding, apiato

I have the APIATO application. And install the library (some wrapper for 3rd part API) by composer.
I need to override classes to add some custom logic into these classes.
Where can I create overridden classes?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to override the packages

1)Extends the class and override the function.

2)implements the class.

3)You have to create a file in the  required container and same way you can use it(same like original usage of the package with overridden file path).